# URL is not changing even after the state is changed . `ui-router`

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using `ui-router` and state provider to route the pages in my application. I have following states written in state provider.

```
.state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'public/msStream/stateFiles/stateHome.html',
        controller: 'stateHomeController'
    })

.state('home.profile', {
        url: '/home/profile',
        templateUrl: 'public/msStream/views/setting/ProfileBody.html'
      })
```

When I am in `home` state. `/home` is added in my URL, but when I switch to `home.profile` state using `$state.go("home.profile)`, my URL is not changing to `/home/profile` but HTML page added in `templateurl` of the same state is getting rendered on front.

I tried adding `/profile` and `/home/profile` in the URL of the state but nothing seems to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're not providing enough information to answer this question.  Add this to your code and see if there's an error changing state: http://pastebin.com/vvpQJ2E5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created [working plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HV44qF4vThRdIn1sdQoF?p=preview)

The paren-child states do inherit a lot. Among other things, also the **`url`**. So we should not use for child the url part coming from parent.

```
$stateProvider
  .state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'public/msStream/stateFiles/stateHome.html',
    controller: 'stateHomeController'
  })
  .state('home.profile', {
    // HERE
    // instead of this
    // url: '/home/profile',
    // we need this
    url: '/profile',
    templateUrl: 'public/msStream/views/setting/ProfileBody.html'
  })
```

Also very improtant note - parent must contain anchor/target/ui-view for its child:

**public/msStream/stateFiles/stateHome.html**

```
<div>
  <h2>this is the home</h2>

  placeholder for child:
  <hr />

  <div ui-view=""></div>
</div>
```

The most important here is the **`<div ui-view=""></div>`** - a placeholder for child view (unnamed)

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/HV44qF4vThRdIn1sdQoF?p=preview)