# Selenium not finding elements on page

Tags: vb.net, selenium

I am using Selenium to test a vb.net site but when I click the btnNoMatch the pages changes and for some reason, it appears that Selenium doesn't update the source code as I get the below error.

The Error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: Unable to locate element: #chkTermsAccept
```

I have tried using sleep, refresh and navigate but no luck. If I avoid the btnNoMatch click and navigate directly to the page then it is able to find the elements on the page but I cant do this as information is meant to be populated into text boxes after the btnNoMatch is clicked.

The Code

```
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://Mysite.development.ie/")

        Dim element As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginUsername"))
        element.SendKeys("UserName")

        Dim element1 As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginPassword"))
        element1.SendKeys("Password")

        Dim element2 As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("LoginBtn"))
        element2.Click()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        Dim element3 As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("CustomerId"))
        element3.SendKeys("1")
        'Wait Time
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(7000)
        Dim element4 As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ClickCustomer"))
        element4.Click()

        Dim element5 As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("cbxNoMobileNo"))
        element5.Click()
        Dim element6 As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnNoNumberConfirm"))
        element6.Click()
driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnNoMatch"))
            element9.Click()

        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)
        'driver.Navigate().Refresh()
        'driver.Url = "http://Mysite.development.ie/Customer/1"
        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000)
        'driver.Manage().Window.Maximize()
        ''Dim wait As WebDriverWait = New WebDriverWait(driver, 4000)
        'wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated((By.Id("id"))))

        Dim element10 As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Id("chkTermsAccept"))
        element10.Click()

        Dim element12 As IWebElement = driver.FindElement(By.Name("txtName"))
        element12.SendKeys("John")

           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(14000)
        driver.Dispose()
```

Thanks for any help with this issue.

Comment: put some explicit wait to find element.

Comment: Don't edit your question editing in the accepted answer... that ruins the value of the question. If people want to see the answer they can look at the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In stead of using thread.sleep use a function like this to wait till the element is visible, you can set the time to wait, and if still isnt found it will through a timeout exception error.

```
    public IWebElement WaitElement(IWebDriver driver, String element)
    {
        IWebElement WebElement;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); //can be changed
        return WebElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(element)));
    }
```

you can call this like, and it will give it time to search for the element.

```
WaitElement(driver, elementXpath).click();
WaitElement(driver, elementXpath).SendKeys(text);
```

or in your case

```
Dim element10 As IWebElement = WaitElement(driver, "//*[@id= 'chkTermsAccept']");
    element10.Click();
```

Comment: I have made the changes you mentioned but it still crashes on the same line only this time i get this error due to the code updates An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException' occurred in WebDriver.Support.dll

Additional information: Timed out after 25 seconds

Comment: Ok that means that it cannot find the elements, are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: just re-checked  there tried by xpath and by the ID for some reason it works when I am on http://Mysite.development.ie/ or which ever url i navigate to originally but when it goes through the site by natural means and the url changes from something like http://Mysite.development.ie/ to  http://Mysite.development.ie/customer/1 it can't find any elements and when I debugged I found the source code for the first page  http://Mysite.development.ie/ not the current page

Comment: hmm what do you mean by natural means?

Comment: I mean the website going through the steps and btn clicks it is supposed to get to the desired destination instead of me forcing the site to navigate to the page I am having the issue on straight off the bath. If I force it to navigated it to the second url where I am having trouble first it find the elements (for example Mysite.development.ie/customer/1) it is only when the url changes that it can't find elements.

Comment: do you think it could be an issue with angular?

Comment: The only thing i can think of is try refreshing the driver             `driver.Navigate().Refresh();`

Comment: maybe the new url will overwrite the previous

Comment: or you could try this to update the handles, might work`driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])`

Comment: i dont think it is a problem with the selenium code it should work, maybe recheck your scripts

Comment: this may help you out take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920991/url-is-not-changing-even-after-the-state-is-changed-ui-router

Comment: your suggestion of  driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles(driver.WindowHandles.Count - 1)) worked, thanks for the help

Comment: You really should be passing in the locator as a `By` class, not as `String`. It will allow you to have a single function that can process any of the locators available... id, css, xpath, etc. rather than having to write a different function for each.